# NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON deserializing invalid GeoJSON

Tags: c#, geojson, system.text.json, nettopologysuite

We are using `NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON4STJ` to convert GeoJSON used in our front-end using Google Javascript API to data stored in a database. A mapper class is used to handle the incoming `string` containing GeoJSON and return a `FeatureCollection` from it:

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory();
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new GeoJsonConverterFactory(geometryFactory));

FeatureCollection? features = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FeatureCollection>(geoJsonString, options);
```

If the incoming GeoJSON contains a feature such as a LineString or Polygon that contains only a single Point, ex:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-122.43652826547623,47.64769550647011]]},"properties":{}}]}
```

An `ArgumentException` is thrown:

> Invalid number of points in LineString (found 1 - must be 0 or >= 2)

I can't really handle this easily on the front-end, as the data can come from multiple external sources that use this converter. I would like to just ignore any features of this type that are invalid. The only way to handle it I have is to catch the `ArgumentException` and return an empty feature collection, but I would like to still deserialize other features in the collection that are valid and include them as well. I haven't found anything in the NTS options to handle this. Is there any?

Comment: You may try to validate the JSON before parsiing, e.g. using https://geojsonlint.com, not sure if they have any API.